# Reduced Rank Regression Variant, literature request

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, reduced-rank-regression

The RRR framework is usually stated as the minimization problem $\min_{A,B} \|Y-XAB\|_2^2$, where $A$ have orthogonal columns and $A\sim p\times k$, $B\sim k\times q$ with $k<\min(p,q)$.
This representation assumes a linear model $Y=XAB+\epsilon$.

I'm interested in the problem
$$\min_{A,B} \|YB^T-XA\|_2^2.$$
Could you provide some references and thoughts to understand how it is connected to RRR?

Thanks.